# How can I make .change() fire when the text changes without using input from a keyboard?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I am using the `jQuery.change()` method and it works fine if I actually change something via the keyboard. Meaning to say that if I type something in the `<input type="text">` field on my HTML page, then I change a character I mouse out the `.change()` method fires.

However, the problem now is that I am changing the text in the `<input type="text">` via jQuery itself and now the `.change()` doesn't fire when the text changes cause it's not via an input keyboard. I have already tried various methods, but it doesn't seem to work. It only works when I do a change via keyboard inputs.

How can I make `.change()` fire when the text changes without using input from a keyboard?

This is the HTML part:

```
<label for="AddLongitude">*Longitude: </label>
<label id="Add_Long_Label" style="color:red"></label>
<input type="text" id="AddLongitude" name="Add_ServiceCompany" 
    placeholder="Tap on the map" maxlength="18" data-clear-btn="true"  readonly/>

<label for="AddLatitude">*Latitude: </label>
<label id="Add_Lat_Label" style="color:red"></label>
<input type="text" id="AddLatitude" name="Add_ServiceCompany" 
    placeholder="Tap on the map" maxlength="18" data-clear-btn="true" readonly/>
```

This is the jQuery part:

```
$("#AddLongitude").change(function () {
            if ($("#AddLongitude").val() == "") {
                $("#Add_Long_Label").text("This field is mandatory.");
                $("#Add_Lat_Label").text("This field is mandatory.");
            }
            else {
                $("#Add_Long_Label").text("");
                $("#Add_Lat_Label").text("");
            }
        });
```

This is the part where the value changes:

```
$("#AddLongitude").val(e.latlng.lng);
$("#AddLatitude").val(e.latlng.lat);
```

where e.latlng.lng or e.latlng.lat is the variable holding the values to be written.

Comment: share code to see what is wrong

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: I have edited the original post

Comment: *"It only works when i do a change via keyboard inputs."* - I think you'll find it would also work if you change via the mouse or *Edit* menu, in other words, the `change` event will fire if the *user* changes the value and then tabs/clicks out of the field, but will not fire if the value is changed by your JavaScript. But you can trigger it yourself by calling `.change()` or `.trigger('change')` after changing the value, like `$(yourSelector).val("new value").change()`.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: ok the code is back guys

Comment: @ChathuraBuddhika - OP did, then somebody else's edit removed it. I've rolled it back to the version that had the code in it.

Comment: Thanks to whoever who rolled it back :)

Comment: So where is the value changing part

Comment: Why using change event on input while it's *readonly*?

Comment: so basically there is a map when the user taps on the map its longitude and latitude is stored written on both my input fields. its read only cause the user is supposed to just tap on the map no need to manually type in the longitude or latitude

Comment: manually call the event like `$("#AddLongitude").val(e.latlng.lng).change();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to trigger change() function manually after changing the value since it is not an user input. change() method fire only user changed the value.

```
$("#AddLongitude").val(e.latlng.lng).change(); 
$("#AddLatitude").val(e.latlng.lat).change();
```

Comment: That is bravo! Thanks for ur help man! Not only your provided an answer you also gave a easy to understand explanation! Kudos! Your awesome Chathura Buddhika!

Comment: You can also use `$("#AddLongitude").trigger('change');`